# The displacement for Hertz Contact theory

Tags: particle-physics, collision, elasticity

Hello I just begin to learn Hertz contact theory and have some questions about the geometry of the contact between the sphere and the plate in the figure below.

1. The displacement $w(r)$is
   $$w(r) = \delta -(R-\sqrt{R^2-r^2})\approx \delta -r^2/2R, \quad if \quad r<<R$$
   How we can get the nearly equal when $r<<R$ ?
2. Based on Wikipedia, $a=\sqrt{R \delta}$. How can we derive the equation?

I'm really happy if you could answer these questions.

[image]